# Fresh SP2010 Install but came with SP1

Tags: cumulative-update

Just realized that the ISO provided to me by infrastructure folks already has SP1 in it. I am assuming that it does not have June CU and that is why I could not still fix the UPS. Here is the iso i got. SW_DVD5_SharePoint_Server_2010w_SP1_64Bit_English_MLF_X17-76080.iso.

So, Should I ran the Server and Foundation June 2011 CUs?

(I hope the built in SP1 also accommodates Foundation SP1. Can someone please verify?)

Comment: What do you mean when you say you couldn't "fix" the UPS? It works in RTM (prior to SP1), it's just not as robust/performant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you downloaded SharePoint Server with SP1 directly from Microsoft, it includes SP1 for Foundation.

And yes, you may want to install June CU (Foundation and Server separately) or install latest CU (For CU's released after Aug 2011, you don't need to install foundation version separately because server CU include foundation version of CU)